# Render different domain without changing the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to deploy all of rails application except the main domain route (`www.<domain>.com/<nothing here!>`), the main domain should render a url from a different domain (a rails application also, but that should be irrelevant).

How to do it without changing the url in address bar? .. Like kind of like using an `include` in php or other languages.

The reason for this is that I want to temporary have the main domain point to older version of the app (with vastly different code) until some time when I am ready to deploy the main domain (all the sub pages are finished and we need them there for some urls from web to open it)

Comment: You can play around with DNS settings?

Comment: Is it possible to make a copy of the landing page to the new rails project/is the old project still under development/changing? If you can make a copy I would think you could then  add a route for `root 'someController#someAction'`? and go about developing the other pages.

Comment: you can deploy your app in new.domain.com with apache or nginx (depend what you are using)

Comment: So no real answer?